# Conflict between hyperref and showkeys with autoref

Tags: hyperref, autoref, showkeys

maybe this is a stupid question but I would like to know why the `\autoref{}` of `hyperref` package conflicts with the `showkeys` package (to allow in `draft` mode to see the labels) even when passing the `final` option to the `documentclass`.

I leave a piece of code

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, final]{article}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}    
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    hidelinks,   
    linktocpage = false,              
    colorlinks = true,  
    citecolor = NavyBlue,     
    linkcolor = NavyBlue,   % colore links        
    urlcolor = NavyBlue,   % web sites links color    
}

%\usepackage{showkeys}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}


\section{The Pythagoras Theorem}\label{sec:pythagoras}
In this section bla bla bla 

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:pythagoras}
    Pythagoras theorem states bla bla bla
    \begin{equation}
        a^{2} + b^{2} = c^{2} \,.
    \end{equation}
\end{theorem}

As may be seen in theorem \ref{thm:pythagoras} or, alternatively, in \autoref{thm:pythagoras}, bla bla bla

\section{Second section}
In this section bla bla bla we refer to \autoref{sec:pythagoras}

\end{document}
```

I know that all I need to do to solve the problem is to comment out the showkeys package when I am done writing but I would really like to know if there is an underlying reason.

In case there is a way to make `showkeys` ''agree'' with `hyperref` without commenting at the end `showkeys`

Comment: the question is not stupid. There is clearly a bug here.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ok thank you by any chance do you know the reason and how to solve it?

Comment: hyperref contains a faulty test. The problem is only with the final option, you could simple comment the package as it doesn't anything useful with final anyway. I will correct hyperref.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ok thanks I finally figured out what the problem is :)